# How can I get the session of 'username' in Django

Tags: django, session, django-csrf, django-sessions, csrf-protection

I'm working in a middleware to get the session of a certain user, for that, I get in header of Ajax request the username and csrfToken of that user.

If it's possible to manually get the session of certain user with just that data? (while session is closed during request, or made from other question)

If so, could you please give me some examples?

**PS:**

The user from who I want to access it's session generated it's CSRF with this code:

```
from django.middleware.csrf import _get_new_csrf_key as get_new_csrf_key

new_key = get_new_csrf_key()

return HttpResponse(
    simplejson.dumps({'token': new_key}), 
    mimetype='application/json'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create manually the user's session, to get this session again.

As you can see here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/

```
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore
s = SessionStore()
# stored as seconds since epoch since datetimes are not serializable in JSON.
s['last_login'] = 1376587691
s.save()
s.session_key
#'2b1189a188b44ad18c35e113ac6ceead'

s = SessionStore(session_key='2b1189a188b44ad18c35e113ac6ceead')
s['last_login']
#1376587691
```

If you know the session_key, you can have it again.

Comment: I've tested an noticed that session_key changes with every request, so I don't think I can use what you say. Anyway, it helped me a lot to make some progress. I have to test it, but maybe I found a way.